# MouseMove Event not static and readonly

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, mouseevent

I'm trying to add a delegate for a "mousemove" event to a method in a class. I'm using the EventHandler that I would use for the Xaml "MouseMove" but it's not available and only "MouseMoveEvent" is(I don't know if that effect things).

I've looked at the 2 different types in meta Data but it doesn't tell me much. I've also tried making the method that it's linked to read only and static but it's not valid.

I'm making the delegate like this:

```
MainWindow.MouseMoveEvent += delegate (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { Project.Mouse_Move(this); };
```

Where MainWindow is the window of my UI. This is the function it's calling

```
public partial class Program
{
   public void Mouse_Move(MainWindow MainWind)
    {

    }
}
```

I'm trying to get the same result as if you would do it through xaml:

```
Title="MainWindow" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove">
```

and method like this:

```
 private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MainWindow` is a type. You need a reference to an actual instance of a window to be able to hook up an event handler to its `MouseMove` event. Try `Application.Current.MainWindow`:

```
Application.Current.MainWindow.MouseMove += delegate (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { Project.Mouse_Move(this); };
```

Or `Application.Current.Windows`:

```
var window = Application.Current.Windows.OfType<MainWindow>().FirstOrDefault();
if(window != null)
    window.MouseMove += delegate (object sender, MouseEventArgs e) { Project.Mouse_Move(this); };
```